# Class Psy/ShellOutput not found when using php artisan tinker

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new project with the

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test-web
```

command. When I tried to use the php artisan tinker to test some stuff described in the documentation I got the following non-stop appearing error:

```
PHP Error: Class 'Psy/ShellOutput' not found in C:/Users/Development/Projects/laravel/test-web/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Shell.php on line 374
```

It kept flooding the command line until I pressed CTRL+C

I haven't found anything related with the error in the web. I also checked the files of the class were there, used composer update, tried laravel new test-web-2 and nothing.

Running php artisan tinker in an older project doesn't give me any error so I think it is about a newer version maybe?
Is there a way to make it work?
I am running it on Windows 10, PHP 7.3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PsySH v0.9.10 had a bug—a missing `use` statement, thanks to a botched `git rebase`—and there was about a twenty minute window where installing it would pick up that version. `composer update` should get you v0.9.11 which is certified bug free! (at least from that bug )

Answer (score 2):

This could be a number of things, depending on what (if anything) you've added to the base distro... but a couple of things I've run into that might help you are:

Clear out the composer autoload cache:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If this doesn't help, it is possibly a namespace/use issue. If you have added any new classes that tinker may be trying to access, make sure the `namespace` matches the `use` statement in any class that uses it.

So, if class **Foo** is namespaced like so:

```
namespace App\Stuff\Foo;
```

make sure that any other class that uses it pulls it in with the correct `namespace`:

```
use App\Stuff\Foo;
```

**Edit:**

Per the OP's comment below, it appears that the `use` clause is indeed the culprit.  It is possible that the latest version is missing the following line in:

**/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Shell.php**

```
use Psy\Output\ShellOutput;
```

For others coming to this question:  While this will repair the issue temporarily, it is *not recommended* to make changes to the vendor files; the next time you update this via composer, it may overwrite your changes.  You may be better served to revert to a stable version until the package is sorted.

Comment: I used a fresh installation of laravel, didn't added or changed anything. Just ran the installation command followed by the tinker command and the error appeared. But I found the error in the file Shell.php: it didn't include the namespace for the class ShellOutput so I added it and now it is working. It surprises me that an error like that appears when I just created a new project and changes to the vendor source code have to be made.

Comment: I agree - that's not a great way to start, but at least you were able to solve it.  Namespaces trip this up more often than we think.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after a fresh installation too, but when I try with another project that just created earlier it didn't have this error.

my solution is add

`use Psy\Output\ShellOutput;`

in

`/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Shell.php`